# Racket: take: contract violation

Tags: stream, functional-programming, lisp, racket

I am using racket v6.5 repl on linux and trying to run example of take function from the stream tutorial https://docs.racket-lang.org/functional-data-structures/streams.html.

However, instead of expected

```
> (take 3 (stream 1 2 3 4 5 6))
- : (Rec
 g1827317
 (U Null
    (Boxof (U (Pairof Integer g1827317) (-> (Pairof Integer g1827317))))))
'#&#<procedure:.../pfds/stream.rkt:41:7>
```

I get

```
> (take 3 (stream 1 2 3 4 5 6))
take: contract violation
expected: exact-nonnegative-integer?
given: #<stream>
argument position: 2nd
other arguments...:
 3
context...:
 /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/list.rkt:151:0: take
 /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
>
```

Comment: Are you using the `take` function from `pfds/stream`, or the `take` function from `racket/list`? You should be using the one from `pfds/stream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use that stream library, you need to require [`pfds/stream`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/functional-data-structures/streams.html) like this:

```
(require pfds/stream)
```

Once you do that, the correct versions of [`take`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/functional-data-structures/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._pfds%2Fstream..rkt%29._take%29%29) and [`stream`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/functional-data-structures/streams.html#%28def._%28%28lib._pfds%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream%29%29) will be available:

```
> (require typed/racket)
> (require pfds/stream)
> (take 3 (stream 1 2 3 4 5 6))
- : (Rec
     anonymous-module1715254
     (U Null
        (Boxof
         (U (Pairof Integer anonymous-module1715254)
            (-> (Pairof Integer anonymous-module1715254))))))
'#&#<procedure:.../pfds/stream.rkt:41:7>
```

Comment: Why require typed/racket? Isn't that what the `#!typed/racket` part does?

Comment: ITYM "#lang typed/racket" ? Yes, that would be one way of making this work. I think that Alex was trying to mirror the style used by the original poster.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by the error because of this name collision.

Comment: @JohnClements Would `(require typed/racket)` overwrite all `#!racket` bindings like `#%module-begin` etc too or would you have a slightly different environment?

Comment: Within a module, I don't think it'll be able to override `#%module-begin` because that's already expanded away. So `(require typed/racket)` only makes sense in a repl environment where you can't use `#lang typed/racket`.

Comment: I'll be honest, the idea of requiring typed/racket as a library is a pretty frightening one, to me. :)